# How can I mount an SMB share over SOCKS proxy on OS X?

Tags: macos, ssh, proxy, smb, socks

I have an SSH-based SOCKS proxy connection for securely connecting to a remote network, which I don't control.

I connect with `ssh -D 3128 ssh.example.com`, and I have a Location set up in System Preferences whose Advanced settings under Proxies sets the SOCKS Proxy to `127.0.0.1:3128`.

This works fine for accessing websites on the remote network that aren't accessible externally, and I can connect to the mailserver for IMAP and SMTP. However if I try to mount any network shares in Finder using an `smb://` URL, the operation times out. Is there some way to get this to obey the system proxy setting?

Comment: No, probably not. SMB is a LAN protocol, and while it can be routed to subnets, it is not designed to be extended over the WAN, and does not support proxy settings. A VPN is a more suitable solution.

Comment: Cisco AnyConnect VPN used to be available, but the version they supported is EOL on Mac. This proxy is the stopgap while they figure out a new long-term VPN solution.

Comment: a similar scenario works fine on an android device when connecting over a system-wide VPN, e.g. you can browse samba shares with VLC or total commander (with the LAN plugin), so instead of regular ssh tunneling you might want to try something like shadowsocks or v2ray which are more flexible, faster and easier to set up than openvpn and which can function as VPNs while also exposing socks and http proxies; v2ray also also has a reverse proxy tunnel mode which is probably what you need

Comment: Hi! did you get this working? I'm kinda stuck with a same situation here.